# Taking random sample of time series in R

Tags: r, random, time-series

I have some asset's returns:

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("^GSPC")
ret<-ROC(Cl(GSPC[,4]))
```

For purposes of my testing I need two blocks of time sequentially, for example all returns for days from 2007-2009 and then all returns from 2011-present, but I need these to be sampled randomly.

Comment: getSymbols("^GSPC")
Error: could not find function "getSymbols"
> ret<-ROC(Cl(GSPC[,3]))
Error: could not find function "ROC"

Comment: Now I get an error saying there is 'no column name containing "Close"' which is not at all surprising sinc the closing column is number 4.